# Can we place Google Adsense on parallax scrolling Wordpress themed website?

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I Request anyone to clarify my doubt. Can we place Google Adsense on parallax scrolling Wordpress themed website?. Is that a violation against Google Adsense policy!
Example site: http://themeforest.net/item/cportfolio/full_screen_preview/6593960

Please give me a feedback.

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Aligning_images_with_ads check this link,there will not be a problem in place your ad in parallax website, be sure your ad limit does not cross in a single page as per ad sense policy.

Parallax is designing technology, you can use it any single page website as well as multipage website.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Answer!